# Can't start "React Native Tab View" project due to "Android project not found" error

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to start [react native app](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view) on Android emulator on Linux.

```
$ git clone git@github.com:react-native-community/react-native-tab-view.git
$ cd react-native-tab-view
$ npm install
$ react-native run-android
```

The last command prints an error: Android project not found. Maybe run react-native android first?

Then

```
$ react-native android
```

prints: Unrecognized command 'android'

Versions:

```
$ react-native -v
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.40.0

$ npm -v
3.10.10
```

Answer (score 2):

From [the author web site](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view/tree/master/example), I can infer that your problem is being caused because after cloning git repo you must go to:

```
cd react-native-tab-view
cd examples
```

Author's instructor says:

> Clone this repository, run npm install within this directory, and open it using XDE.

I understand that **this directory** means **https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view/tree/master/example**

I Hope it helps.

Comment: Does it work for you? For me when I execute `npm install --save react-native-tab-view` command (inside `example` folder) it prints `UNMET DEPENDENCY react@~15.4.2` and `UNMET DEPENDENCY react-native@git+https://github.com/exponentjs/react-native.git#sdk-13.0.0` errors.

Comment: I think it might not be made for running just using react-native since author says _and open it using XDE_. I'm not sure, I cant find any open issue regarding to this.

Answer (score 2):

Answering myself (tested on MacOS 10.12). XCode, Nodejs and NPM must be installed.

```
cd react-native-tab-view
npm install
cd example
npm install
```

Download and install [XDE](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v14.0.0/introduction/installation.html).

Start XDE. Press "Project" button, open `react-native-tab-view/example` directory.

Press "Device->Open on iOS Simulator".

In case it fails you can find a suggestion in the output, like the command below

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app
```

Then just allow expo to be installed on the simulator.

I think the procedure is similar on Linux or Windows.